# Weighted randomness in java game algorithm

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a random generator that i want to use for 4 items.

What i want to happen is i want each item to have a weighted randomness. So of course the one with the highest randomness gets chosen more than the others.

I have 4 items that the random generator can chose from.

```
Random rand = new Random();

int itemNumber = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
```

so basically i just want each item to have the ability to have a weight over each other. I also would need to be able to change the weight throughout the programs life cycle. So the weight of each item won't be final. I have a pool that i use to recycle the items to save on memory so when a item is chosen it is pulled from the pool.

Answer (score 4):

Add the weights up to a total, select a random number from that range, and select the items by range.

If you have 4 items, with, respectively, weights of 4, 3, 2, 1, then your total is 10 (0-9). 0-3 is the first item, 4-6 is the second, 7-8 is the third, and 9 is the last.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you are saying and it makes PERFECT sense. Quick question,  will i need and if statement to test if each integer is in a certain range or what would you suggest??

Comment: And for example what if the integer changes and the total changes how would it know what range should be the correct range for each coordinating weighted items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like below.  Pass the weights in - and it'll come back with a corresponding random integer between 1 and number of weights passed in.

```
public weightedRandom(int[] weights) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<weights.lenght; i++) {
        total += weights[i];
    }

    int nnum = rand.nextInt(total);
    for(int i=0; nnum > 0; i++) {
        nnum -= weights[i];
    }

    return i + 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this method but for some reason i get random numbers in the negaitves?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 Sorry, my mistake in the last `return` statement.  I updated my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

If each item has a weight, then you can generate a random number 0-(sum(weights)) and pick based on which range it falls in.

ex:

```
int weights[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
int sum = 10;//I'm cheating, it will need to be calculated
Random rand = new Random();
int choice = rand.nextInt(sum)+1;
for (int x = 0; x < weights.length; x++)
  if (choice-= weights[x] <=0)
    //use item X
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an arraylist of the possible items, and as the weight of the items change, add more of that kind of item into the array, and call a random index of the array for the random item. Like so:

```
ArrayList<int> rand = {1,2,3,4}
//This would add more weight to the number 1
rand.add(0,1)

//then to choose a random item, just call for a random index
rand.get((int)(Math.random*rand.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a small algorithm, that first select items randomly depending upon there perentage weights and then makes a random select from those selected items. :)

int weightPercentages[] = {50,10,20,20};

```
int randomPercentage =(int) (Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

int countSelected = 0;

Arraylist<Integer> selectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int lop=0; lop<weightPercentages.length; lop++){
     if(weightPercentage[lop]>randomPercentage)
          selectedItems.add(weightPercentage[lop]);
}

int selectedItem = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random()*selectedItems.size());

System.out.println(randomPercentage[selectedItem]);
```